# Android TextView width

Tags: android, layout, textview, width

I already searched internet for the solution, but none of them works for me...
I have 3 EditText's and 2 TextViews. I can't figure out how I can trim those TextViews (space after '+' and '=').

[image]

there is my .xml file:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="4"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="="
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/wynik"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="4"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>
 </TableRow>
```

Comment: Why are you using a TableRow? I would replace it with an HorizontalLinearLayout.

Comment: ok but how to move the buttons to the new line?

Comment: Use a Vertical `LinearLayout` that contains 2 Horizontal `LinearLayout` (as childs), one for the `EditText`s (first line) and the second for the buttons (second line).

Comment: Thx, btw gravity is not working for linearLayout? I just wanted to center one of the layouts...

Comment: You should take a deep look to how android layouts work. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

We could keep you solving these little issues, however you will never understand how it works if you don't learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:paddingRight="0dp" should work
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout by setting [weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) like this. This will do the trick for you.

```
<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="40dp" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="8">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
         android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wynik"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</TableRow>
```